# I receive ANR when calling URLconnection

Tags: java, android, urlconnection

EDIT: This is run in AsyncTask, I should have mentioned this.

I have received many ANR's on this code block:

```
    URL url = new URL(sURL);
        URLConnection connect = url.openConnection();
        connect.setConnectTimeout(R.integer.timeoutLengthWithACapitalT);
        connect.setReadTimeout(R.integer.timeoutLengthWithACapitalT);
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connect.getInputStream())); //Problem Line
```

R.integer.timeoutLengthWithACapitalT is 1000

I don't know what is causing this, I believe it should time out. However, I get a stack trace for ANR.

Stack Trace:
https://pastebin.com/hwJhGfVX

Comment: You should not be executing this code on the main application thread.

Comment: How did you run this without an Asynctask?

Comment: Please yous multithread

Answer (score 0):

You should run your network call not in main thread. I prefer using AsyncTask for all network calls. You can use below code snippet

```
private class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<URL, Integer, Long> {
     protected Long doInBackground(URL... urls) {
         //your main network call code
         return result; //this return will invoke onProgressCompleted
     }

     protected void onPreExecute() {
        //network call in progress, you can show a loaded here if you want
     }

     protected void onPostExecute(Long result) {
        //Once network call is completed
     }
 }
```

You can also check Android Docs for more details
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

Comment: Thank you, I forgot to mention I am using Async so this is not the issue.

Comment: I added it on pastebin for you. I have more if you need, but they are all roughly the same.

Comment: Do you have any suggestions?